# debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive Permission denied, please try again

Tags: ssh, backuppc

I am trying to ssh-copy-id root@linclient and continue to get this message after entering the password. Output of:

```
ssh -vvv root@linclient
```

is below:

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@linclient: Permission denied (publickey, password,keyboard-interactive).
```

/var/log/auth.log:

```
Jun  3 13:03:28 liclient sshd[10337]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Jun  3 13:03:28 liclient sshd[10454]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jun  3 13:03:28 liclient sshd[10454]: Server listening on 192.168.0.120 port 22.
Jun  3 13:03:31 liclient sshd[10457]: Connection from 192.168.0.103 port 55298 on 192.168.0.120 port 22
Jun  3 13:03:31 liclient sshd[10457]: Failed publickey for root from 192.168.0.103 port 55298 ssh2: RSA SHA256:J7Gm0ZS6icNOdQ5
```

> In the sshd.config (below) the relevant settings I played with and no
>   success still asking for password authentication and fails after 3 attempts.

```
PubKeyAuthentication yes  
AuthorizedKeysFlle %h/.ssh/authorized_keys  
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes  
UsePAM yes  
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password or PermitRootLogin yes      
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

But for any user, I copied the key on the **local** machine with success and then ssh without password. Any other users can ssh without password, the only root is not allowed.

It seems that the **root** cannot log in without password from remote machines. The **sshd.config** on the clients are identical with the one on the server.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you set a root password on the machine?

Comment: yes, there is a root password